# To reference VSS.SDK in typescript. Error : VSS is not defined

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, ambient

I am trying to use `vss-web-extension-sdk` from *node_modules*, when I compile the project is compiled.

But when I upload it says;
[image]

A small piece of code from a typescript file

```
VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: false,
        usePlatformStyles: true,
        usePlatformScripts: true
    });
```

Directory structure of **vss-web-extension-sdk** (under *node_modules*)

[image]

I also tried to *reference* and *import* the sdk where I use it, but could not make things work. My attemps as below and errors that I got as following...

```
/// <reference path = "../../../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/index.d.ts/" />
```

> Error : *File
> '.../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/index.d.ts/' is not
> under 'rootDir' '.../src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source
> files.ts(6059)*

```
import  "../../../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk"
```

> Error: *Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '../../../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk' in ...*

```
import "vss-web-extension-sdk"
```

> Error: *Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vss-web-extension-sdk'
> in ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I include and initialize VSS.SDK in the html file then I am able to use it from .tsx files too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <script src="../../lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize the VSS sdk
        VSS.init({
            explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
            usePlatformScripts: true
        });
        VSS.ready(function () {
            VSS.register(VSS.getContribution().id, function (context) {
                return {
                    // ...
                  };
            });

            VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
        });
    </script>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** If you get

> Resource blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options:
> nosniff)

after referencing the SDK from HTML file, look at this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41319855/9851619