# Ionic Angular Live-Reload Not Finding Files when Reloading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I am facing an Issue with the Ionic Live Reload. When I do changes in the editor, the change gets recognised but then the web view is just empty. But the Console full of errors.

I don't have a clue where the Problem is. I've adjusted my package.json to the Tabs starter but that also didn't change a thing. I've could imagine that there is something wrong with the routes it gets, according to the errors.

[image: error messages]

In the starter App, the live-reload works like a charm. Every help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "name": "tab-application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev-ios": "ionic build && ionic capacitor copy ios && ionic capacitor open ios"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.5.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/globalization": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/theme-detection": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.4.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "capacitor": "^0.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mady": "^3.4.0",
    "ngx": "^2.4.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.65",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.164",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well any code would be helpfull, but maybe this stackoverflow helps ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728554/resource-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff

Comment: Sure. What do you think could be helpful? package.json? Because, as mentioned, I really don't know where the error is.

Comment: Yes it could be helpfull, what did you do/change when it crashed. And did you stop and restart the `ionic serve` yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Also compared my package.json with the one from the starter application and adjusted that.

In addition I deleted the node_modules and did a clean npm install.

Comment: @Tom package.json is available now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Problem. The Index.html file wasn't correctly configured. The base path should be '/' and clearly not './'. Definitely a stupid mistake.