# CORS Error. cannot access assets folder in parent directory from index.html

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, liveserver

I am learning JavaScript from the course (JavaScript Essential Training) by Morten Rand-Hendriksen. I downloaded all the exercise files and Using Firefox and VSCode and Live Server running locally, I tried to load the example code below (example 5.02) in the browser.

It does not display the CSS style showing the picture of the backpack. In the console, I get this error:

```
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

*I set Tracking Content to Off in Settings (see screenshot) but it did not help.*

I verified that the file is present "..\assets\images\everyday.svg"

***Update**: I tried to load it directly in Firefox, not LiveServer. I see in the console, Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/Me/Documents/Learn/JS/05_03/Backpack.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).*

**Actual result**

[image: actual result]

**Expected Result:**

[image: expected result]

The code is here:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BackpackPacker</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200..700&family=Work+Sans:wght@100..900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="../assets/style.css"
      type="text/css"
      media="all"
    />
    <script type="module" src="Backpack.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="siteheader">
      <div class="site-title">BackpackPacker</div>
      <div class="site-description">All backpack packing, all the time.</div>
    </header>
    <main class="maincontent"></main>
    <footer class="sitefooter">
      <p>
        Demo project for JavaScript Essential Training, a LinkedIn Learning
        course.
      </p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Backpack.js**

```
class Backpack {
  constructor(
    name,
    volume,
    color,
    pocketNum,
    strapLengthL,
    strapLengthR,
    lidOpen,
    dateAcquired,
    image
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.volume = volume;
    this.color = color;
    this.pocketNum = pocketNum;
    this.strapLength = {
      left: strapLengthL,
      right: strapLengthR,
    };
    this.lidOpen = lidOpen;
    this.dateAcquired = dateAcquired;
    this.image = image;
  }
  toggleLid(lidStatus) {
    this.lidOpen = lidStatus;
  }
  newStrapLength(lengthLeft, lengthRight) {
    this.strapLength.left = lengthLeft;
    this.strapLength.right = lengthRight;
  }
  backpackAge() {
    let now = new Date();
    let acquired = new Date(this.dateAcquired);
    let elapsed = now - acquired; // elapsed time in milliseconds
    let daysSinceAcquired = Math.floor(elapsed / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    return daysSinceAcquired;
  }
}

export default Backpack;
```

**script.js**

```
/**
 * Traverse the DOM tree using querySelector() and querySelectorAll()
 * @link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector
 * @link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll
 */

import Backpack from "./Backpack.js";

const everydayPack = new Backpack(
  "Everyday Backpack",
  30,
  "grey",
  15,
  26,
  26,
  false,
  "December 5, 2018 15:00:00 PST",
  "../assets/images/everyday.svg"
);

const main = document.querySelector(".maincontent");

const content = `
  <article class="backpack" id="everyday">
    <figure class="backpack__image">
      <img src=${everydayPack.image} alt="" />
    </figure>
    <h1 class="backpack__name">${everydayPack.name}</h1>
    <ul class="backpack__features">
      <li class="backpack__volume">Volume:<span> ${
        everydayPack.volume
      }l</span></li>
      <li class="backpack__color">Color:<span> ${everydayPack.color}</span></li>
      <li class="backpack__age">Age:<span> ${everydayPack.backpackAge()} days old</span></li>
      <li class="backpack__pockets">Number of pockets:<span> ${
        everydayPack.pocketNum
      }</span></li>
      <li class="backpack__strap">Left strap length:<span> ${
        everydayPack.strapLength.left
      } inches</span></li>
      <li class="backpack__strap">Right strap length:<span> ${
        everydayPack.strapLength.right
      } inches</span></li>
      <li class="backpack__lid">Lid status:<span> ${
        everydayPack.lidOpen
      }</span></li>
    </ul>
  </article>
`;

main.innerHTML = content;
```

**CSS file in ../assets/style.css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.siteheader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.site-title {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.siteheader:after {
  display: block;
  margin: 4rem 0;
  content: "⚍⚌⚍";
}

.maincontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-width: 60rem;
}

.page-header {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.page-header__heading {
  margin-top: -1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-header:after {
  margin: 4rem auto;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  width: 4rem;
}

.backpack {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  /* padding-bottom: rem; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0 3rem;
}

.backpack:after {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  display: block;
  grid-column: span 2;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  width: 4rem;
}

.backpack__image {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.backpack__name {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.backpack__features {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.backpack__features li {
  padding: 0.2rem 0;
}

/* Subgrid. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid */
@supports (grid-template-columns: subgrid) {
  .backpack__features {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    gap: 0 1rem;
  }

  .backpack__features li {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  }
}

.lid-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}
.lid-toggle:hover,
.lid-toggle:focus {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}

.lid-toggle:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.sitefooter {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

[image: tracking set to off in Settings]

Comment: Have you tried anything from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728554/resource-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff)?

Comment: @gbac Yes, I checked that the file is present "..\assets\images\everyday.svg"

Comment: The error is pointing to your css file.

Comment: @gbac the css file is present in ../assets/style.css I edited the question to show the css file.

Comment: To troubleshoot further, try moving the css file into the same directory as your html file, and then change the href path to `"style.css"`

Comment: @gbac now it works! but why cannot it see a file in `../assets` Is it something in FireFox?

Comment: Since that works, it seems that something is off in your file hierarchy compared to your original href path. Hard to give you the exact solution, since I don't know how your files are set up. However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location) may help you to get it right. Your css file will definitely work in the assets folder, you just have to make sure that the href pointing to the file is correct. Would you like me to post this as an answer so that your question doesn't remain unanswered?

Comment: @gbac yes, please post as an answer. But the issue persists with other examples. For instance, with example 5.04. Same issue. The hrefs are correct. I wonder if Firefox or Windows 11 has a security restriction not allowing access to parent directory `..\\`

Comment: @gbac when I type `..\assets\style.css` in the Windows File Explorer address bar, it opens the css file correctly. This tells me the href is correct.

Comment: I tried to load it directly in Firefox, not LiveServer. I see in the console, `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/Me/Documents/Learn/JS/05_03/Backpack.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).`

Comment: @gbac I changed the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting CORS error, and you are accessing your site locally (via filesystem, or Live Server) this error typically means that there is something wrong with your `href` path, `src` path, or with your file hierarchy. **If you are using a node server, then this answer is probably not for you.**

Filesystem and Live Server handle parent directories differently.

Live Server uses your opened folder (in VS Code) as the root, and does not let you go to parent directories above that.

Let's say that the folder that you open in VS Code contains only your `index.html` file, and your assets folder is in it's parent directory.

In this case, Live Server will not let you access the files in your assets folder.

Typically, `../` takes you to the parent directory, but in Live Server, if you are already set in the 'root' directory (the folder that is open in VS Code), then `../` will not take you anywhere.

This is different from your local filesystem, where `../` will take you up as many parent directories as you wish, until you reach the root drive.

**What I suggest:**

Keep your file hierarchy as simple as possible.

Have your index.html in the root folder for your project, and then keep your assets in subfolders, rather than parent directories.

- Project Folder

Contains index.html and your assets folder

- Assets Folder

Contains script.js and style.css

Then, in your html file, change your paths to `assets/style.css` and `assets/script.js`

This will allow your site to work for both Live Server and your local Filesystem. It will also make things easier when deploying your website online.

**EDIT:** Whatever folder you open in VS Code will be your root directory, and Live Server will let you access the files from there and all sub directories. If you are unable to move your assets to the project directory, then make sure you open the folder that contains your assets folder in VS Code. Then navigate to your html file and start the Live Server from there.

Comment: upvoted and thank you, but it does not solve my issue. There are several index.html each in a sub folder and they need to share the assets folder. I am trying to open this index.html in live server. In VSCode, I am trying to set multi root folder for live server but it still does not work.

Comment: I added an edit to my answer for your use case

Comment: please see the solution below

Comment: Adding that line in `settings.json` doesn't change anything, since `./` points to the current directory, which is already the root by default. The rest of your solution is exactly what I explained in my edit.

Comment: ok, I did not understand what you had written here [gbac] "make sure you open the folder that contains your assets folder in VS Code. Then navigate to your html file and start the Live Server from there."

Comment: ""make sure you open the folder that contains your assets folder in VS Code. " Isn't that different in effect from "add folder to workspace"?

Comment: In regards to the functionality of Live Server, they are the same.

Comment: ok, I have accepted your answer - Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

**Note: see alternative solution at the end.**

After a lot of searching, I found this is a VSCode feature for LiveServer.
In the JS folder which contains the sub-folders, I saw there is a .vscode folder which contains a file `settings.json`.
In the file, I added the line for root location.
So my Settings file looks like this.

**settings.json**

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "liveServer.settings.root": "./"
}
```

In VSCode, under File menu, I selected "Add Folder To Workspace" and added the JS folder

[image: add folder to workspace]

Now when I open VSCode, I click the poorly chosen icon that is normally used for "copy" and it opens up VSCode Explorer.

[image: vscode]

So all I have to do now is to open index.html in whichever subfolder and right-click and choose **"Open in LiveServer"**

**Alterative Solution:**

1. In VSCode choose Open Folder in the File menu

[image: In VSCode choose Open Folder in the File menu]

2. In VSCode, lower right corner (assuming Live Server extension was installed), click "Go Live".

[image: click Go Live]

3. you will see a directory listing; now you can go into a subfolder and open its index.html

[image: list directory]

You will find that assets are automatically available.

[image: click index.html]