# How to force mime type on js files with apache?

Tags: reactjs, apache, deployment, mime-types, uberspace

I host my react app on uberspace. They use apache and have `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` enabled. Which I like.
However when I host my react app I get the following error in firefox console:
`The resource from “url...” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`
I figured out that the mimetype of the js is for some reason text/html. Saw that in network tab in the firefox developer tools.
I added `AddType text/javascript js` to my *.htaccess*, but it doesn't help.
I think the problem is, that the js is served as html mimetype and I don't know how to force it to be mimetype js.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: And I don't know how to add `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/javascript" />` to the file since it's scrambled.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but I solved my similar problem.

Check if the file path is correct or that the file is there.

I used SvelteKit static build and I only uplouaded the index.html file and not the _assets which contain files with new randomly generated filenames.

Reference: [Resource blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728554/resource-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff) dav's answer

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you’re actually requesting the correct URL to the JavaScript file.**

All reasonably configured web servers should return `Content-Type: application/javascript` for `.js` files by default. There shoudn’t be the need to override the standard configuration using an `.htaccess` file.

I had the same issue, but when I looked closely, I noticed a 404 error that occurred right before the script error:

[image: Refused to execute script]

So the browser is (rightfully) refusing to parse the 404 error document as a script.