# How do I add tailwind CSS to HTML?

Tags: frontend, tailwind-css

I am getting this error  "The resource from “https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.2.1/dist/tailwind.min.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."  As such, the style options are not loading. What could be the issue?

I created a tag for tailwind CSS but it does not lead the required styles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728554/resource-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff.

Can you show us your <head> where you are importing these scripts?

Comment: Check if the added path is correct for the Tailwind CSS.

Comment: Have you tried to open the link you use ? If you open your css link for version 3.2.1, it say "Cannot find "/dist/tailwind.min.css" in tailwindcss@3.2.1"

Answer (score -1):

Use the below script in the `<head>` tag in your Html file and then you can use tailwind CSS classes.

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: Not suitable for production